# Pandas np.where with matching range of values on a row

Tags: python, pandas

**Test data:**

```
In [1]:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(
       {'AAA' : [4,5,6,7,9,10], 
        'BBB' : [10,20,30,40,11,10],
        'CCC' : [100,50,25,10,10,11]});
In [2]:df
Out[2]:
   AAA  BBB  CCC
0    4   10  100
1    5   20   50
2    6   30   25
3    7   40   10
4    9   11   10
5   10   10   11

In [3]: thresh = 2
        df['aligned'] = np.where(df.AAA == df.BBB,max(df.AAA)|(df.BBB),np.nan)
```

The following `np.where` statement provides `max(df.AAA or df.BBB)` when `df.AAA` and `df.BBB` are exactly aligned.  I would like to have the `max` when the columns are within the value in `thresh` and also consider all columns.  It does not have to be via `np.where`. What ways are there to approach this?

So for row 5 it should be `11.0` in `df.aligned` as this is the max value and within `thresh` of `df.AAA` and `df.BBB`.

Ultimately I am looking for ways to find levels across multiple columns where the values are closely aligned.

**Current Output with my code:**

```
df
   AAA  BBB CCC aligned
0   4   10  100 NaN
1   5   20  50  NaN
2   6   30  25  NaN
3   7   40  10  NaN
4   9   11  10  NaN
5   10  10  11  10.0
```

**Desired Output:**

```
df
   AAA  BBB CCC aligned
0   4   10  100 NaN
1   5   20  50  NaN
2   6   30  25  NaN
3   7   40  10  NaN
4   9   11  10  11.0
5   10  10  11  11.0
```

The desired output shows rows 4 and 5 with values on `df.aligned`.  As these have values within `thresh` of each other (values 10 and 11 are within the range specified in `thresh` variable).

Comment: In your output, shouldn't `aligned` of row 5 be 11.0 rather than 10.0?

Comment: That is the desired output with 11.0 returned.  My code doesn't look at all columns yet and also needs to use thresh.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why did you write "So for row 5 it should be 11.0 in df.aligned as this is the max value and within thresh of df.AAA and df.BBB. " then? And what's the exact logic you want with tresh?

Comment: Thresh is equal to 2 so I want np.where to match on values within thresh.

Comment: What do you mean by "within tresh"? Do you mean that df.AAA should be `> tresh`? Or do you mean that since thresh is 2, you take AAA and BBB (`df.iloc[:,:2]`), if tresh is 3 you take AAA,BBB,CCC

Comment: If any value in AAA BBB or CCC is within thresh distance of other value on same row it is a match and should return Max of these values.  So for row 5 the range of values is 10 to 11 so all within thresh distance between each other.  Therefore return max of these values which is 11. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Within thresh distance" to me means that the difference between the `max`
 and the `min` of a row should be less than `thresh`. We can use [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with parameter `axis=1` so that we apply the lambda function on each **row**.

```
In [1]: filt_thresh = df.apply(lambda x: (x.max() - x.min())<thresh, axis=1)
100 loops, best of 3: 1.89 ms per loop
```

Alternatively there's a faster solution as pointed out below by @root:

```
filt_thresh = np.ptp(df.values, axis=1) < tresh
10000 loops, best of 3: 48.9 µs per loop
```

Or, staying with pandas:

```
filt_thresh = df.max(axis=1) - df.min(axis=1) < thresh
1000 loops, best of 3: 943 µs per loop
```

We can now use [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and calculate the max of each row that matches (hence the `axis=1` parameter in `max()`again):

```
In [2]:  df.loc[filt_thresh, 'aligned'] = df[filt_thresh].max(axis=1)

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
   AAA  BBB  CCC  aligned
0    4   10  100      NaN
1    5   20   50      NaN
2    6   30   25      NaN
3    7   40   10      NaN
4    9   11   10      NaN
5   10   10   11     11.0
```

---

#### Update:

If you wanted to calculate the minimum distance between elements for each row, that'd be equivalent to sorting the array of values (`np.sort()`), calculating the difference between consecutive numbers ([np.diff](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html)), and taking the `min` of the resulting array. Finally, compare that to `tresh`.

Here's the `apply` way that has the advantage of being a bit clearer to understand.

```
filt_thresh = df.apply(lambda row: np.min(np.diff(np.sort(row))) < thresh, axis=1)

1000 loops, best of 3: 713 µs per loop
```

And here's the vectorized equivalent:

```
filt_thresh = np.diff(np.sort(df)).min(axis=1) < thresh

The slowest run took 4.31 times longer than the fastest. 
This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 67.3 µs per loop
```

Comment: This is very nice, thank you. Is there a way to have this also consider partial matches if only 2 columns are within thresh?  So it would see row 4 cols BBB CCC are within thresh?

Comment: Apologies if not clear.  I will ask a new question if this is better?  It is already useful what you showed me and appreciated.

Comment: Nice solution. I think it'd be much more efficient to use DataFrame level operations to get your Boolean index instead of a row level `apply`, i.e. `filt_thresh = df.max(axis=1) - df.min(axis=1) < thresh`.

Comment: Actually, I forgot about `np.ptp`.  I think that would probably be fastest:  `filt_thresh = np.ptp(df.values, axis=1) < 2`.

Comment: @root: added your suggestions above, thanks. I didn't think about speed given the small size of this dataset, but yes the apply is completely unnecessary given that there's a pandorable way with `df.max(axis=1)...`.

@adele: I updated my answer to include your new requirements: calculate the min distance between elements.

Comment: Added timings too